# What does FixedLenNullInSource in sp_help mean?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Taking a look around FixedLenNullInSource is for compatibility with SQL 2000, but what does it actually mean?

Comment: Even in 2000 BOL this is listed as ["For backward compatibility only."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933429%28v=sql.80%29.aspx). You'd probably need to find the docs for an even earlier version.

Comment: Thanks Martin Smith, been tryign to track down the meaning in the SQL server 7.0 docs, but looks like the meaning has been lost in time! I wonder if any old-schoolers know what it means?

Comment: [Looking at the definition of `sp_help`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13508162/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-values-for-fixedlennullinsource-and-trimtrailingbla/13508747#13508747) it actually doesn't appear to mean much these days. It is hardcoded to return "yes" if the column is nullable and one of `'varbinary', 'varchar', 'binary', 'char'`

Comment: Thanks @MartinSmith you should pop your comment in as an answer. That's good enough for me, I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In SQL Server 2008 the definition of `sp_help` shows this is hardcoded to return "yes" if the column is nullable and one of `varbinary`, `varchar`, `binary`, `char`

```
   'FixedLenNullInSource' = 
   CASE
        WHEN Type_name(system_type_id) NOT IN ( 'varbinary', 'varchar', 
                                                'binary', 'char' ) THEN '(n/a)'
        WHEN is_nullable = 0 THEN @no
        ELSE @yes
    END
```

In SQL Server 2000 it is defined differently as

```
   'FixedLenNullInSource' = case  
      when type_name(xtype) not in ('varbinary','varchar','binary','char')  
       Then '(n/a)'  
      When status & 0x20 = 0 Then @no  
      Else @yes END
      /* ... */
      from syscolumns
```

The meaning of the `stats` bits in `syscolumns` in SQL Server 2000 is not fully documented but I found a [SQL Server 7.0 SP4 upgrade script](http://pastebin.com/0iEPVjHp) that sets the column values as follows (`0x20` = `32` in decimal)

```
+ CASE WHEN (type_name(xtype) IN ('text', 'image')
                                AND (colstat & 0x2000)!=0)
                            OR (type_name(xtype) IN ('binary', 'char', 'timestamp')
                                AND (typestat&1)=0 )
                            THEN 32 ELSE 0 END      -- COL_FIXEDNULL, COL_NONSQLSUB
```

I couldn't find much additional information when googling for either `COL_FIXEDNULL` or `COL_NONSQLSUB` but did find out that the storage of `NULL` values for fixed length datatypes changed in SQL Server 7. In previous versions nullable fixed length datatypes were silently converted to variable as per the following table.

```
+----------------------------+-----------+
| char                       | varchar   |
| nchar                      | nvarchar  |
| binary                     | varbinary |
| datetime                   | datetimn  |
| ﬂoat                       | ﬂoatn     |
| int, smallint, and tinyint | intn      |
| decimal                    | decimaln  |
| numeric                    | numericn  |
| money and smallmoney       | moneyn    |
+----------------------------+-----------+
```

This is discussed for SQL Server in KB 463166 ([only available in French](https://support.microsoft.com/fr-fr/help/463166)) and from looking at the Sybase documentation it appears that is [still the case in that product](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1600/doc/html/san1390612248048.html).

From SQL Server 7.0 onwards a `NULL` `CHAR(100)` column took up the whole of the declared fixed column length in the fixed length data section of the row (until sparse columns were introduced in 2008 - which change the behaviour again).

I presume that this `bit` in `syscolumns.status` differentiated between the two different storage formats.

Comment: Great answer, thanks @Martin and thanks for the extra detail.