# Is there a way to change the values for FixedLenNullInSource and TrimTrailingBlanks?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there a way to change the values for `FixedLenNullInSource` and `TrimTrailingBlanks`?

I use `sp_help` to compare the output from different servers to see if the tables are identical. `FixedLenNullInSource` and `TrimTrailingBlanks` are throwing my comparisons off.

Comment: I am comparing standard test database with client's database. No, DB is not upgraded from an earlier version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TrimTrailingBlanks` relates to the `SET ANSI_PADDING` option when the table was created. You might be able to change that without recreating the whole table in a similar way to [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10010042/update-ansi-nulls-option-in-an-existing-table/10072304#10072304) for changing the `ANSI_NULL` option.

Otherwise you would need to recreate the table with the desired semantics selected.

Looking at the definition of `sp_help`

```
   'FixedLenNullInSource' = 
   CASE
        WHEN Type_name(system_type_id) NOT IN ( 'varbinary', 'varchar', 'binary', 'char' ) THEN '(n/a)'
        WHEN is_nullable = 0 THEN @no
        ELSE @yes
    END
```

so it appears different values for `FixedLenNullInSource` just indicate that the nullability of the column is different and that it is one of the 4 specified datatypes. You would need to fix that with `ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN`

You are probably much better off using a third party tool to compare the databases such as Redgate SQL Compare or SQL Server Data Tools or even just querying `sys.tables` and `sys.columns` yourself rather than using `sp_help` though.