# What is FixedLenNullInSource in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sp-help-operator

I cannot find information what is `FixedLenNullInSource` in SQL Server?

Can anyone explain simply?

[image]

Comment: What query are you using to get this output?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13508162/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-values-for-fixedlennullinsource-and-trimtrailingbla (the answer shows the definition), note that the [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187335%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) says it is for backwards compatibility only. So other than academic curiosity, you shouldn't really care about its value.